# Unable to retrieve message with JmsTemplate.receive() that was created with MessageProducer.send()

Tags: spring-jms

I'm using Spring Boot to start an embedded ActiveMQ broker, and I'm using spring-jms to dynamically register JMS endpoints for topics at runtime. I got that part to work, and when I create a JMS message and send it off to the topic, it ends up getting consumed by my listener. So far, so good. Inside the listener, I want to send a simple ACK message to a different topic if the JMS header "JMSReplyTo" is set in the message. If it is, I create a MessageProducer with the destination set to the topic set in the header, and then send the ACK message. The code seems to work, or at least so I think because I'm not getting any errors. However, in my test case, after sending the initial message, I'm trying to read the ACK coming back on the other topic, and the call times out. I'm using JmsTemplate to both send the original message, as well as consume the ACK. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what. This is the relevant Spring Java config part showing the SessionAwareMessageListener:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionAwareMessageListener")
SessionAwareMessageListener<TextMessage> createSessionAwareMessageListener() {
  return new SessionAwareMessageListener<TextMessage>() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(TextMessage message, Session session) throws JMSException {
      log.info(" Received: {} ", message.getText());

      // Prepare an ACK reply message
      final ActiveMQTextMessage textMessage = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
      textMessage.setText("ACK");

      // Send the ACK message back to the replyTo address of the incoming
      // message. 
      if (message.getJMSReplyTo() != null) {
        log.info("Sending ACK message to {}", message.getJMSReplyTo());
        // session.createTopic(message.getJMSReplyTo().toString());
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
        producer.send(textMessage);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

In my Spock integration test, I'm creating a MessageProducer and sending the message off through a JmsTemplate instance:

```
...other stuff here...
MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
  @Override
  public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    log.info("Sending text message")
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a test")
    message.setJMSReplyTo(new ActiveMQTopic("test"))
    return message
  }
}

... code that registers the JMS endpoint goes here...

JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate)
assert jmsTemplate
jmsTemplate.send("bar", messageCreator)
```

Sending of the message is successful, and it ends up handled by the SessionAwareMessageListener shown earlier. But when I try to use JmsTemplate.receive() to retrieve the ACK message, it blocks until the call times out, and returns null. There is no particular listener or dynamically created endpoint registered on the topic for the ACK messages, so I thought it would be possible to consume the messages using JmsTemplate.receive(). Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't really figure out what. This is the code snippet where I'm trying to receive the ACK:

```
jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(2000L)
Message received = jmsTemplate.receive("test")
assert received instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage
log.info("Received message: ${received}")
assert ((ActiveMQTextMessage) received).text == "ACK"
```

I'd be grateful for pointers to a better way of doing this. I'm really just experimenting at this point. I know that I will need to register endpoints dynamically, and possibly forward messages to other topics. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to use topics for request/reply messaging, especially on the reply side.

1. The reply might arrive before the `receive()` has subscribed to the topic; the broker will drop such messages, unless that subscription is durable.
2. You generally only want the reply to go to the originator.

Use a queue instead of a topic, particularly for the reply.

Consider using a `JmsTemplate` for the reply instead of creating your own producer; if you are using a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and session transacted (you should always use `sessionTransacted` with a DMLC to avoid losing messages), the template will automatically use the same session.

If you expect multiple responses to a single message, it's ok to use a topic on the request side but, again, the number of replies will be indeterminate unless the subscriptions are durable - you can't tell on the producer side how many consumers will receive it.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that makes sense. I figured I was doing something wrong. My test case works sometimes, and sometimes not, so I'm probably running into the scenario you describe.